# Not able to switch users while resuming from suspend on a Dell Inspiron X8300

Tags: 11.10, ati, 64-bit, suspend

I am on DELL Inspiron X8300 Desktop with ATI Radeon 5450 grahics card running Ubuntu 11.10, 64-bit.

I am having a problem when switching users while resuming from suspend. When clicked on "Switch users" while resuming from suspend, it takes me to the gdm login screen and after I enter my password, the screen goes blank and I see no activity. 
I cannot switch the monitor using CTL+ALT+F1 and I cannot even logout using CTL+ALT+BACKSPACE. The only way out is to restart using a hard power off.

However, I am able to resume from suspend if I am not switching users and I am also able to switch users when not resuming from suspend. So, it seems like I have a workaround, by resuming the old session and then switching users, but it is annoying since my wife uses the desktop at night and I use it at the morning.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It just so happened that it had nothing to do with suspend. The problem was I could switch user from my main account, but I could not switch back.
The other account had some grahpics issue for which I decided to remove the ATI drivers installed with 11.10 and downloaded & installed the lastet driver from ATI/AMD which seemed to solve my problem